# How to make the post submitted not disappear on reload HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a website, and I want the post to stay there when I reload the page. And I don't want it to disappear when I reload it.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [localStorage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_storage#Usage) *or* connect to a database in the backend.

If you're a beginner, just do some research on
localStorage.